# Filter function not working well with the highest date in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I want to filtre my data like that: 
Of every number in the column A (1 to 5) take the highest date value in column B, and then put the result of each of them in the second table. It works when the dates are in order like the case of the number 1 and 2 (F3:I4), but it is not working with the number 3, because its dates are not in order in column B.
This is the link of my worksheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YuFoCUBMFo5nqYK20tcVHms2dr84yIsEIH2vhbqrlEQ/edit?usp=sharing.
I made it editable by everyone with the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SORT(SORTN(SORT(A3:D, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))
```

[image: 0]